# Prime numbers sum

Tags: python

Any ideas for simplifying this code? It is taking far too long, but maybe that is because my limit (`2000000`) is super high.

```
def is_prime(x):
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x == 2:
            break
        elif x % i == 0:
            return False
            break


total = 0
for num in range(2, 2000000):
    if is_prime(num) != False:
        print(num)
        total += num

print(total)
```

Comment: Your `is_prime` function never returns true; if it doesn’t return False, it returns None.

Comment: There are tons of code for prime number generation, you only need to search a bit.

Comment: As for performance: the way you’re testing for primes takes a quadratic number of divisions. For 2 million primes, that’s 4 trillion divisions. That’s going to take a very long time. If you want this to be faster, you have to implement a more efficient prime test algorithm. Or, better, a prime generation algorithm that doesn’t depend on testing each number, like a sieve. There are plenty of good examples online.

Comment: I would suggest making a [prime sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) using numpy (because numpy arrays are much more efficient than python lists or tuples)

Answer (score 1):

To speed it up a bit, make your upper bound the square root of `x`.
If there are no factors before that point, there will be no other factors after it too.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `is_prime()` you are using a very brute force method to exhaustively check every possible number to see if it is a divisor of x. As mentioned in the comments you can instead only check up to `sqrt(x)` as the other half of the multiplication would have already been checked. Additionally it is very common to cut the number of calculations in half by checking if x is divisible by 2 only once and then only iterating over odd numbers. With these two modifications alone you can gain a lot of speed.

```
import math

def is_prime(x):
    if x == 2: #2 is prime
        return True
    if x % 2 == 0: #divisible by 2
        return False
    for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(x)),2): #only odd numbers up to sqrt(x) starting from 3
        if x % i == 0: #divisible by i
            return False
    return True #we made it through the loop without finding a divisor
```

An example of generating all primes up to `x` using a prime sieve and numpy might look something like this:

```
import numpy as np

sieve = np.ones(x,bool)
sieve[:2] = False #0 and 1 are not prime
for i in range(2,int(x**.5)):
    if sieve[i]: #`i` is prime therefore mark all multiples of i as not prime
        sieve[i*2::i] = False
primes = np.where(sieve)[0] #extract primes as indices of `primes` that are true
```